# Is it possible to upgrade directly from Datastage 7.5.3 to 11.7.1?

Tags: version, upgrade, datastage

We are migrating from Datastage 7.5.3 to 11.7.1. I was wondering whether we need to upgrade to an intermediate version of Datastage? Is there any conversion tool available? Any inputs from people who have experience in a similar upgrade are appreciated. Thanks

Comment: For in place upgrade, I think it is only available to upgrade from 11.5 to 11.7. You can check: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/place-upgrade-ibm-infosphere-information-server-115-version-11700

Answer (score 0):

There is no option for in-place upgrade from DataStage v7 directly to Information Server v11.

You will need to install Information Server 11.7.1 (either to same machine in side-by-side config if machine has enough resources for both environments, or to a new server).   You can then export all of your existing DataStage jobs in v7 environment to dsx file that you can then import into the new environment.

More information on migration steps can be found here: 
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZJPZ_11.7.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.productization.iisinfsv.migrate.doc/topics/top_of_map.html

Though this document does not list specific steps for DataStage v7.5, the steps for DataStage v8 are equivalent as long as you export jobs as dsx files since istool did not exist in DataStage v7.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes we have a totally new server which is compatible with Datastage 11.7. Sorry I missed mentioning that in my post. My question was more regarding the jobs/configurations as such. I am assuming it wouldn't be a straight forward export and import and it will all start working in the new version. Like stages/functions or configuration files like dsenv etc which may not be compatible or don't exist in new versions etc. Or anything else in general which I need to be aware of.Thanks

Comment: Due to size limit on reply, please see my separate answer in this topic in a few minutes about changes you need to be aware of when moving jobs from v7.5 to v11.7.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There have been many changes to DataStage between versions 7.5 and 11.7 which you need to be aware of when moving jobs from old release to new release.   We have documented these changes for DataStage 8.5, 8.7, 9.1 and 11.3 releases.  Since you are jumping past all these releases, all the documents are relevant and I will link them below and HIGHLY recommend reviewing them as they can affect behavior of jobs and also result in errors.  In some cases we document in these technotes environment variables that can be set which will switch back to the old behavior.

Additionally, in the last few releases a number of the older enterprise database stages for various database vendors have been deprecated in favor of using newer "Connector" stages that did not exist in v7.5.   For example, DB2 Enterprise stages should be upgraded to DB2 Connector, Oracle stages to Oracle connector, etc.
We have a client tool, the Connector Migration tool which can be used to create new version of job with the older stages automatically converted to connector stages (you will still need to test the jobs).

Also, when exporting jobs from v7.5, export design only...all jobs need to be recompiled at new release level so exporting executable is waste of space in this case.

If you do have a need to also move hash files and datasets to new systems, there are technotes on IBM.com that dicuss how to do that, though I cannot guarantee the format of datasets have not changed between 7.5 and 11.7.

You will find that in more recent releases we have tightened error checking such that things which only received warnings in past may now be flagged as errors, or conditions not reported at all may now be warnings.  Examples of this include changes to null handling, such as when field in source stage is nullable but target stage/database has field as not nullable.   Also there are new warnings or errors for truncation and type mismatch (some of those warnings can be turned off by properties in the new connector stages)

### Here are the recommended technotes to review:

Null Handling in a transformer for Information Server DataStage Version 8.5 or higher
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/433863

Information Server Version 8.7 Compatibility

https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/435721

InfoSphere DataStage and QualityStage, Version 9.1 Job Compatibility
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/221733

InfoSphere Information Server, Version 11.3 job compatibility
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/514671

DataStage Parallel framework changes may require DataStage job modifications
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/414877

Product manual documentation on deprecated database stages and link to Connector Migration Tool: 
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSZJPZ_11.7.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.conn.migtool.doc/topics/removal_stages_palette.html

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot Brian. I will go through all of the above links, I am sure it is going to help us.

Comment: A question regarding the Connector Migration Tool- Do we import the dsx from 7.5 into the 11.7.1 version and then run the Connector Migration Tool to convert the stages to the new version, OR, is the tool run before importing the dsx into 11.7.1 ? I read in some article that this Connector Migration Tool only supports datastage 8.5 and above. Correct me if I am wrong.Thanks.

Comment: The Connector Migration Tool connects to a DataStage project, just like other DataStage clients, so it can only work with jobs that are already imported into the project.  Thus you need to first import your v7.5 jobs (via DSX file) into an 11.7.1 project.  You then connect to that project with CMT and can select jobs to migrate...If it is a large project the initial display of content may take a while because it reads in the design of every job in project so you can expand twisty to see what migrate-able stages each job has.  You then select to migrate original job or modify new copy of job.